# content of /userinfo response from wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I installed v5.1.0 of wso2 identity server and executed an OpenID Connect flow. Finally, I wanted user profile information to be retrieved from the server (via `/oauth2/userinfo` endpoint).
In contrast to other mailings, I only receive a one-item-answer `{ "sub":"admin }`. By default, there should also be `phone_number`, `email` and others. It used the playground2 application to verify and yes, only `{ "sub":"admin" }` is returned.
I used `scope=openid` for the authz code request as well as `schema=openid` in the /userinfo query as in the descriptions.
I tried to set various claims in http://wso2.org/oidc/claim to supported, required, etc. but no change.

How to I configure the server to return more details?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue in Identity Server 5.1.0 and this is reported [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4250). You can follow the discussion and try applying the fixes as patches to identity server. Other wise you can try 5.2.0-M1 or a later version which this issue has been fixed.